# move an attachment name in a file based on a pattern match inside the file

Tags: linux

Requirement : I have 3  text files a, b and c with some text and the filename of a csv attachment.

Each file has a specific pattern that I need to search for.  If it matches, move the file of the attachment to match that specific pattern.

For example:

File a has Pattern *apples are red* and the Attachemnt filename is *filename.csv*.

The script should look for "apples are red" pattern and if found, move the filename.csv to 'apples are red.csv'

Similarly file b has Pattern *mangoes are yellow* and the the Attachement filename *filename2.csv*.

The script should look for "mangoes are yellow" pattern and if found move the filename2.csv to 'mangoes are yellow.csv.

Any ideas?

I can grep for the pattern in file 'a', but how can I extract the filename.csv from file 'a' and move it?

### sorry about that  alcanzar... the data in a.txt looks like this

Email Report: apples are red

The results are attached as a CSV file.

Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="filename1.csv"

### Content-Description: filename1.csv

My requirement is to grep for string after Email Report:
and the filename1.csv in the content-description and then rename
filename1.csv to apples are red.csv or better to apples_are_red.csv    . 
The string after Email Report: keeps changing for every file . 
So the .csv has to renamed to what ever the string is after "Email Report:" .

Comment: Perhaps you should show some example files, because it's not exactly clear what files contain what information, or where you are getting your "attachment filenames"...

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please try to format it well. Use CTRL-K on code or text blocks and don't give unnecessarily large fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your updated requirements, this should come close:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *.txt
do
    PATTERN=`grep "Email Report" $i | cut -c 15-`
    ATTACHMENT=`grep "Content-type" $i | cut -d\" -f2`

    echo "Checking for pattern $PATTERN in $ATTACHMENT"
    if [ ! -z `grep -l "$PATTERN" "$ATTACHMENT"` ]
    then
      echo mv $ATTACHMENT $PATTERN.csv
    fi
done
```

Comment: the file names are a.txt b.txt and so on ..contains lot of txt and the pattern "apples are red"  and the attachment file name . I need to grep for the pattern and the attachment filename and then rename the attachment with the pattern .

Comment: sorry about that ... the data in a.txt looks like this Email Report: apples are red

The results are attached as a CSV file.



Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="filename1.csv"
Content-Description: filename1.csv

Comment: sorry about that  alcanzar... the data in a.txt looks like this
-----Email Report: apples are red  The results are attached as a CSV file. Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="filename1.csv"
Content-Description: filename1.csv ---  My requirement is to grep for string after Email Report: and the filename1.csv in the content-description and then rename  filename1.csv to apples are red.csv or better to apples_are_red.csv The string after Email Report: keeps changing for every file . So the .csv has to renamed to what ever the string is after "Email Report:"